# Adding Event Listener to an image created in js

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create a bunch of images inside js and add Event Listeners to each of them so that they trigger function when clicked.

I use this function to create images.

```
function image(fileName) {
    const img = new Image(100, 100);
    img.src = `images/${fileName}`;
    return img;
}
```

When I try to add an event listener with
`image.addEventListener(...)`
It compiles but doesn't work when drawing the images later.

I have also tried adding an id to the image and using `getElementById()` to add the listener, it doesn't compile with the event listener reading null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: You mentioned that you tried `image.addEventListener` but shouldn't that be: `img.addEventListener`?

Comment: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) doesn't really help me because I'm not using jQuery.
It being `image.addEventListener` instead of `img.addEventListener` is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The eventListeners only work when the element is added to the DOM, which isn't in your case.

If you add your image to the DOM then you can add a working evenListener.

```js
function image(fileName) {
    const img = new Image(100, 100);
    img.src = `images/${fileName}`;
    // Or any other node
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    return img;
}
// Now you can bind eventListeners to the returned img element
```

Comment: This does allow me to get images that I can click on but they appear on the document body and not on specific spots on a canvas where I want them.

Comment: I read more about DOM and there no way to append elements to a canvas. Is there any way to have a clickable image in the canvas or do something similar to append elements to the canvas.

Comment: Ah it’s on a Canvas. Then You have to add the event listener on the canvas element and track your image position so you can check whether the mouse x and y are inside the image boundaries when you click on the canvas.